# Novel about a woman who is transformed into an elf

Tags: story-identification, novel, elves

So this is going to be very vague for which I apologise. At least 10 years ago I read a sci-fi/fantasy hybrid novel in a library about a woman (she possibly lived in a junkyard or tinkered with broken technology trying to fix it, but I'm not sure).

She met an elven prince, possibly rescued him, ended up having what she thought was a one-night-stand with him, but woke up to find the encounter had transformed her into an elf, and that she was considered to be married to him now. She was understandably upset that she had not been informed that this would happen, but she eventually helped the prince save his people from some threat.

I can't remember much else about it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 9):

This would be the Elfhome (Tinker) series by Wen Spencer.  See [her website](http://www.wenspencer.com/elfhome-series/).  It appears to be a match for all of your details.

> Inventor, girl genius Tinker lives in a near-future Pittsburgh which now exists mostly in the land of the elves. She runs her salvage business, pays her taxes, and tries to keep the local ambient level of magic down with gadgets of her own design. When a pack of wargs chase an Elven noble into her scrap yard, life as she knows it takes a serious detour.